# postfix send email subject breaks the FROM

Tags: php, email, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, postfix-mta

I am using `postfix` to send an email to the user, but the problem is it breaks the words where it finds the space.
Here is the screenshot:
[postfix-send-email](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1609911/572c7d6a7c1946edd79c17a9f39a384c)

[image]
PHP code to send an email:

```
<?php
$subject = "Status Of mail";
$message = "Test Email using Postfix Apache2";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: 'The Travel Worthy' 'pathik@gmail.com"\r\n";
$send = mail('test@yahoo.com', $subject, $message, $headers);
if($send)
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: You might want to show us some code. Preferably where you create and send your email. We're not mind readers!

Comment: which code do you want? php mail function code?

Comment: The code where you build the email you're having trouble with, maybe? You should really [read about how to ask questions here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: this is not coding issue, it might have postfix issue that breaks the words where it finds the space. still i edited my question @MagnusEriksson

Comment: This line looks totally wrong... `$headers .= 'From: 'The Travel Worthy' 'pathik@gmail.com"\r\n"`. Is this your actual code?

Comment: it is dynamic, but here i put static.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123752/discussion-between-pathik-vejani-and-magnus-eriksson).

Comment: _**Sight**_. You ask for help but you won't even show us the actual code (pseudo code doesn't cut it, specifically if there is some silly error). You claim to know that it is a POSTFIX-issue but you still tag the question with php, apache2 and ubuntu. Good luck... I'm off...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it has been resolved, it was just silly mistake i made!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
$headers .= 'From: 'The Travel Worthy' 'pathik@gmail.com"\r\n";
```

with

```
$headers .= "From: The Travel Worthy <pathik@gmail.com>\r\n";
```

Comment: @PathikVejani no problem :)